# amazon like Jquery slider integration

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I am new to jquery

I try to integrate the slider like the exact functionality of `amazon.com` `Most Wished For in Video Games slider` which is displayed at the bottom.

For this I tried the `carouFredSel` plugin. But I couldn't achieved the same.

The  hover functionality for scrollbar, scroll bar tied with image scroll, no need the image hover effect  etc...

I googled a lot. I couldn't find the exact same.

Anybody please give a solution. Thanks

Comment: post some code and the expected behaviour

Comment: I use this following http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel/#carousel-image-and-text

Here the main problem is I couldn/t able to drag the scroll bar.